# how to read the value returned by sys.exit() and store it in a variable

Tags: python, perl, exit-code

I have a python script with `sys.exit(0)` or `sys.exit(-1)` in the end (0 or 1 depending on whether an error has occurred). How do I store this 0 or 1 in a variable? For example, in an environment variable or in a variable used by a perl script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your python code in a normal shell you have the `$?` variable:

```
   $ python yourscript.py
   $ echo $?  # this will echo the sys.exit value
```

This is also valid inside your perl script:

```
 system("python yourscript.py");

 if ($? == -1) {
        print "failed to execute: $!\n";
    }
    elsif ($? & 127) {
        printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
    }
    else {
        printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in windows use `%ERRORLEVEL%`:

```
CMDPROMPT>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win 32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.exit(-1)
CMDPROMPT>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-1
CMDPROMPT>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]     on win 32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.exit(0)
CMDPROMPT>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
CMDPROMPT>
```